# I want to get the list item of a SharePoint List(On Premise), Please share the code to the get the List Item using the properties in C#

Tags: c#

The Properties, I am in need are inside the List Item, I can able to see it by clicking the property of 'Find by Values', inside that we can see the items of the list.

I have tried this following code
`Console.WriteLine(ListCollection.Title);`
and getting this error!!!

> Severity Code Description Project File    Line Suppression State Error
>   CS1061    'ListItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Title'
>   and no extension method 'Title' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ListItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)    Connect
>   Console   C:\Users*****\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Connect
>   Console*******\Program.cs    30 Active

Referred from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee534956(v%3Doffice.14)

```
Console.WriteLine(ListCollection.Title);
```

I am expecting to get the values of the 'Key'(Title).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not super clear what you are asking but 
There is no Title on ListItemCollection or ListItem so I am not sure what you want to get.

You can access each ListItem inside a ListItemCollection using ListItemCollection[x].
In your case:

```
Debug.WriteLine(ListCollection[0].Text);
```

see this example:

```
    ListItemCollection x = new ListItemCollection();
    x.Add(new ListItem() { Text = "test1" });
    var y = new ListItem() { Text = "test2" };
    x.Add(y);

    Debug.WriteLine(x[0].Text);
    Debug.WriteLine(y.Text);
```